# Scala Jackson Unmarshalling - Conflicting setter definitions for property "config": com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#setConfig(1 params) vs

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I have a small Scala program to unmarshall JSON but getting the error: "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "config": com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#setConfig(1 params) vs com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#setConfig(1 params)
"

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

object JsonUtil {
  val sampleJson =
    """{
                         "operator" : ">",
                         "displayName" : "Months Since Start",
                         "fieldName" : "months_since_start",
                         "fieldType" : "double",
                         "expression" : "12"
                     }"""


  case class Rules(operator: String,
                   displayName: String,
                   fieldName: String,
                   fieldType: String,
                   expression: String)

  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.readValue(sampleJson, classOf[Rules])


}
```

What am i doing wrong here? i use Scala scalaVersion := "2.11.11"